# Tensor manipulations in Landau & Lifschitz "Classical theory of fields"

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

Landau & Lifshitz "[Classical theory of fields](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780080250724/the-classical-theory-of-fields)" section 6 p. 19 define:
$$
df^{ik} = dx^i dx'^k - dx^k dx'^i
$$
and
$$
df^{*ik}=\frac{1}{2} \; \epsilon^{iklm}df_{lm} \tag{6.11}
$$
and states:

> "It is obvious that $df^{ik} df^*_{ik}=0$."

I am unable to see that this is true. Can anyone help me?

Comment: When I was a student, we sometimes spent hours on a Landau's "it is obvious that......" !

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218658/the-dual-of-a-surface-element-in-4-space

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might help to forget about the d's.

Instead, let $F^{ik}=(v^i w^k -v^k w^i)$.

So, $F^{*}_{ik}= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{iklm} (v^l w^m -v^m w^l)$.

Altogether, we have $F^{ik}F^{*}_{ik}=(v^i w^k -v^k w^i) \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{iklm} (v^l w^m -v^m w^l)$.

Remember that $\epsilon_{iklm}$ is totally-antisymmetric.

Can you finish?

Comment: It's still not obvious to me, since $\epsilon_{iklm}=\epsilon_{lmik}$... Doesn't it?

Comment: @hft Expand out the right-hand-side. Then, look at each term. In each term, what multiplies the $\epsilon_{iklm}$?